# Restricting APNS based on types, Swift 3

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

In my current application, APNS is up and running with no problems.  However, I am confused on how to handle filtering certain payloads based on notification types.  Please refer to the picture below:

[image]

From top to bottom, the UISwitches corresponds to:

- All Notifications
- Group Notifications
- Upload Notifications
- Content Notifications
- Comment Notifications

respectively.

Each `UISwitch`'s state is saved in `UserDefaults` for later use.  However, I am having trouble thinking of how I would be able to use it properly to restrict messages from coming in.

Are there client-side methods/ways to restrict incoming notifications from appearing, if the payload includes custom key/value information? Ex// Payload includes {"type": "comment"}.

**Edit:**
The desired effect, when a `UISwitch` is "off", is for the banner UI to not display, the sound to not trigger, but allow for payload information of that type to still be delivered (for updating the `UITabBarController`'s badge).

It seems like a modified version of Silent Notification might be needed, as having no payload whatsoever restrict updates for the `UITabBarController`'s badge.  Any reference or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A client-side solution for this would be pretty wasteful, but if you are making a client for an API which you have no access to, then your latter idea is plausible, I would go with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the API, a server-side solution would be best. However, if you really need a client-side solution, it is possible as well.

You cannot decide whether to show a push notifications to the user or not, the system automatically delivers push notifications that are not silent and displays them to the user, while silent push notifications are not displayed, only delivered to the app. You cannot change this behaviour.

However, there is at least one workaround I can think about right now. Deliver all push notifications silently and depending on the user settings, for the notifications that are turned on, deliver a local notification copying the contents of the silent push notification immediately. This way, you can filter the notifications based on their category after they have been delivered. Bear in mind that if the notification is time crucial, this might not be the best approach, since there might be a slight delay between the push notification and the local one.

Comment: Assuming a server-side solution is plausible, would a reasonable way to handle this be for the `UISwitch`'s selector function to make an API call to trigger a flag enabling/disabling the sending of messages of the particular type?

I have edited my original post with a more concrete explanation of the requirements for this app feature, which I had mistakenly not made clear in the original post.

Comment: If you still need the payload to be delivered, then you should toggle the `content-available` property of the notification to change between silent and displayed notification. And yes, you should implement an API call that is triggered when a switch is toggled.

Comment: I think I got it.  Just to be clear: (1) I'll need to enable App Settings -> Capabilites -> Background Modes -> Remote Notifications. (2) Implement API call when switch is toggled. (3) Have the API adjust the `content-available` property of the payload; 1 for silent, 0 for regular, pertaining to the particular "type" of the notification.  This way, no UI is shown, sound is disabled, however I'll still receive the payload and be able to update UI in the background.  Please kindly let me know if I've glossed over anything.  Much thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is what you need to do.